# How to get index number of element in array in mongodb with C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

For example :

```
Update.Set("City.[dynamicIndexNumber].Town","blabla");
```

instead of

```
Update.Set("City.0.Town","blabla");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var element="City."+dynamicIndexNumber.ToString()+".Town";
Update.Set(element,"blabla");
```

Comment: @BurakkGümüş then put that in your question.. his answer matches what you're asking for in the question